# not change My Container Color with method setstate in GestureDetector

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

im going to change colors Container when
click on GestureDetector but nothing change...  .
like this image:and im click on vector men and women..
and nothing change...i use linear gradiant and List of color please help me to solve this problem

[image: my app]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'icon_content.dart';
import 'reusable_card.dart';

const BottomContainerHeight = 80.0;

List<Color> inactiveCardColoursFemale = [Color(0xFF42A5F5), Color(0xFF039BE5)];
List<Color> activeCardColoursFemale = [Color(0xFF303F9F), Color(0xFF283593)];
List<Color> inactiveCardColoursMale = [Color(0xFFFBC02D), Color(0xFFFFB300)];
List<Color> activeCardColoursMale = [Color(0xFFFF6F00), Color(0xFFE65100)];

enum Gender {
  male,
  female,
}

class InputPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const InputPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _InputPageState createState() => _InputPageState();
}

class _InputPageState extends State<InputPage> {
  Gender selectedGender = Gender.female;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
        title: const Text("Iman Bmi"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
              child: Expanded(
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        selectedGender = Gender.female;
                      });
                    },
                    child: ReusableCard(
                      colour: selectedGender == Gender.female
                          ? inactiveCardColoursFemale
                          : activeCardColoursFemale,
                      cardChild: IconContent(
                        svgPicture: 'assets/2.svg',
                        label: 'women',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        selectedGender = Gender.male;
                      });
                    },
                    child: ReusableCard(
                        colour: selectedGender == Gender.male
                            ? activeCardColoursMale
                            : inactiveCardColoursMale,
                        cardChild: IconContent(
                          svgPicture: 'assets/3.svg',
                          label: 'men',
                        )),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )),
          Expanded(
            child: ReusableCard(
              colour: [Colors.deepPurple, Colors.purple],
              //colour: Color(0xFF65E655),
              cardChild: Row(
                children: [],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
              child: Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: ReusableCard(
                  colour: [Colors.teal, Colors.tealAccent],
                  //colour: Color(0xFF65E655),
                  cardChild: Column(
                    children: [],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: ReusableCard(
                  colour: [Colors.amber, Colors.yellow],
                  //colour: Color(0xFF65E655),
                  cardChild: Column(
                    children: [],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
            width: double.infinity,
            height: BottomContainerHeight,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                    begin: Alignment.topRight,
                    end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                    colors: [Colors.deepOrange, Colors.deepOrangeAccent]),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and My Reusable Card Class Code: i use to linear Gradiant and List of color

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    class ReusableCard extends StatelessWidget {
    ReusableCard({required this.colour, required this.cardChild});

    //required this.colour
    final List<Color> colour;
     final Widget cardChild;

     @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: cardChild,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          //color: colour,
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topRight,
            end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
            colors: colour,
          ),
          //Color(0xFF65E655)
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: change `ReusableCard` to stateful widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the first `Expanded` widget inside your `Column` should fix your issue.

```dart
// Change this
Column(children: [Expanded(child: Expanded(child: Row()))])

// to this
Column(children: [Expanded(child: Row())])
```